# Не работает .write в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Изучая Python, при работе с файлами, я наткнулся на очень неприятную проблему! Причём ладно бы если бы так у всех... Объясняю. Я читал документацию, смотрел видео-уроки, у всех один и тот же код и он работает, когда же я решил его повторить, чтобы для начала хоть понять что к чему, он попросту у меня не заработал!!!

Вот сам код:

```py
t = open('/Text1.txt', 'w')
t.write('text is write...')
t.flush()
t.close()
```

Как видно, цель заключается в том, чтобы открыть файл и записать туда строку `'text is write...'`, но я очень разочаровался, когда, открыв .txt файл, не обнаружил там новой строки. Как видно, выше я уже пробовал разные советы из интернета (по типу .flash) - не помогло... Посоветуйте решение...

Comment: Убрать / из пути.

Comment: Как писали выше убрать слеш из пути тогда файл будет в директории запуска скрипта. Или используйте полные пути `D:\\Text1.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь создать файл в корневой директории. Скорее всего, у Вас нет таких привилегий. Запустите код в консоли, запущенной от имени администратора. Или измените директорию.

Пример создания файла в текущей директории:

```py
t = open('./Text1.txt', 'w')
t.write('text is write...')
t.close()
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду, под словами "Вы пытаетесь создать файл в корневой директории"? Просто файл у меня уже создан, я его хотел открыть в питоне.

Comment: @Daniil Приведите, пожалуйста, конкретную ошибку в вопрос. Так будет легче помочь Вам.

Comment: В том то и дело что ошибок, при исполнении кода нет, даже в консоли ничего лишнего нет. Просто не идёт запись в текстовый документ.

Comment: @Daniil Где Вы ищете текстовый документ? На диске `C`?

Comment: нет, не на диске С, на другом.

Comment: Спасибо, указал абсолютный путь, заработало.